# Расположение (ориентация) кнопок

Tags: android, android-layout, button

У меня в боксе допустим 6 кнопок, в изначальном положении они изображении 3 на 2 а при повороте экрана набок они так и остаются и при этом расстояние между ними растягиваются. Как мне сделать так что бы при повороте экрана они шли друг за дружкой и при этом в одну строку помещалось столько кнопок сколько позволяет экран?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button88"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button377" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="128dp"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button36"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button377"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Добавьте код, для лучшего понимания проблеммы

Comment: [flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Comment: [ConstraintLayout flow](https://proandroiddev.com/awesomeness-of-constraintlayout-flow-aa0b5edd5df)

Answer (score 0):

На android есть стандартный путь для решения данной проблемы. Нужно использовать две разметки для разных ориентаций:

**res/layout-port/layout.xml** - тут расположить вашу разметку (будет работать для вертикальной ориентации)

**res/layout-land/layout.xml** - тут расположить новую разметку, в которой описать разметку (кнопки в одной строке) для горизонтальной ориентации.

Более подробно о квалификаторах ресурсов - [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)